# Can't I use many ifelse in else?

Tags: r, if-statement

This code is a complex if.
I write this code because I want to use the flow control to decide whether the user can eat the cake or not.
The variables a, b, c, d are some indexes that the user will put in.
In this place, I have already set these indexes.
Based on the indexes, the nested if will give some responses.

```
a <- 1 ; b <-  2 ; c <- 3 ; d <- 3

index <- sum(a, b, c, d)

if(index > 11){print("enjoy the cake right now!")
}else{
  if(b == 1 | c == 1){"You don't have the right to eat cake."
  }else{
    ifelse(b == 3, "go to ATM and take money right now", 
           ifelse(b == 2, "use the budget of tomorrow first",print("") )
    )
    print("bb")
    ifelse(c == 4, "run to the cake store and burn some calores ", 
           ifelse(c == 3,"ride youbike to the cake store", 
                  ifelse(c == 2, "ride youbike to the cake store",print(""))))
    print("aa")
    }
        }
```

My expectation is:

```
[1] "use the budget of tomorrow first"
[1] "bb"
[1] "ride youbike to the cake store"
[1] "aa"
```

But the result is:

```
[1] "bb"
[1] "aa"
```

Why the R program didn't run the "ifelse" part and just printed "bb", "aa"?
Is this because the "else" can't include "ifelse"?

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple `ifelse` in `else` but it doesn't print the string here is because `ifelse` returns the value and does not print them by default. You need to explicitly `print` them. If you add `print` around those strings in `ifelse` it would work. However, as you have scalar input to compare here you can use `if`/`else` instead of `ifelse` which is usually used for vector inputs.

```
if(index > 11) {
  print("enjoy the cake right now!")
} else {
  if(b == 1 | c == 1) {print("You don't have the right to eat cake.")
  } else{
    if(b == 3) print("go to ATM and take money right now")
          else if(b == 2) print("use the budget of tomorrow first") else print("") 
     print("bb")
    if(c == 4) print("run to the cake store and burn some calores ")
        else if (c == 3) print("ride youbike to the cake store")
           else if(c == 2) print("ride youbike to the cake store") else print("")
     print("aa")
    }
}

#[1] "use the budget of tomorrow first"
#[1] "bb"
#[1] "ride youbike to the cake store"
#[1] "aa"
```